# How to deploy a Solana program using Solana JavaScript SDK?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, solana-sdk

The [documentations](https://docs.solana.com/cli/deploy-a-program) explain how to deploy a Solana program using the CLI tools. Is there a way to achieve that in JS/TS using the `@solana/spl-token` client?

Edit: What I actually meant is `@solana/spl-token` or `@solana/web3` or the JavaScript SDK in general. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Deploying programs involves sending transactions to the Upgradeable BPF Loader program, which can be done using tools from "@solana/web3", it's just not very convenient. https://docs.solana.com/developing/on-chain-programs/deploying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically you can deploy with javascript, but it is quite lengthy and usually not recommended due to the amount of transactions that need to be executed.

Solana Playground runs [deploy using just typescript](https://github.com/solana-playground/solana-playground/blob/cd77e52d53e67f00daad977bea305f03cf4df4d2/vscode/src/commands/deploy/deploy.ts#L19) implementing the [BPFUpgradableLoader Program](https://github.com/solana-playground/solana-playground/blob/master/vscode/src/commands/deploy/bpf-upgradeable/bpf-upgradeable.ts#L180).

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR NO.

If it exists, Maybe Jon C. is the best person to answer that.

The `@solana/spl-token` library, only enables you to interact with the `Token Program` and the `ATA program` when using JS/TS.

Are you facing any challenges using the cli tools?

Comment: I'm trying to keep my whole workflow around TypeScript and have my own set of functions to interact with Solana network. Using CLI isn't reliable in my case since I won't have full flexibility especially when it's about key management.

Comment: Do you have a Solana Program? If upgrading your program is a concern you can make your program immutable.

Comment: Actually, I plan to keep the program upgradable since I'm planning to add more features in the future.

Comment: Well, the only option that I would suggest which is counter intuitive is to write TS/JS scripts that call the solana-cli commands. 

Also, if you are writing a solana program I'd highly suggest using anchor, but you can also write solana programs in Python using seahorse or even Move but I am not certain about the product readiness of the last two.

Comment: As far as I understand, it is possible to make custom transaction instructions with `@solana/web3`. I think I can implement this functionality, but I need help finding out what transactions are being sent when deploying a program and their payload schema.